# How to make sure that the root of the given equation is a multiple of $\pi$?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I am using  `FindRoot` to find the roots of this two-variable equation

```
 f := 
  250 (1 + t)^2 Cos[(2 π Sqrt[t])/
     3]^2 Sin[π Sqrt[t]]^2 - ((-1 + t)^2 Sin[
      Sqrt[t] (2 π - y)])^2;
dif = D[f, {{y, t}}];
FindRoot[dif == {0, 0}, {{y, 0.4}, {t, 13.86}}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 50];
sub = {y, t} /. %
f /. %%
```

and the result is:

$ \{0.41887902047863909846168578443726705122628925325001, 
14.062500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\}$

As can be seen, the component $t$ is a rational number, then, is there a way to ask Mathematica to check whether the component $y$ is a multiple of $\pi$ or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f := 250 (1 + t)^2 Cos[(2 π Sqrt[t])/
       3]^2 Sin[π Sqrt[t]]^2 - ((-1 + t)^2 Sin[Sqrt[t] (2 π - y)])^2;
dif = D[f, {{y, t}}];
sol = FindRoot[dif == {0, 0}, {{y, 0.4}, {t, 13.86}}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 50];
f /. sol

(* 0.*10^-94 *)
```

To check if `y` is a rational multiple of `Pi`, divide by `Pi` and use [`RootApproximant`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootApproximant.html)

```
yapprox = RootApproximant[(y /. sol)/Pi] Pi

(* (2 π)/15 *)

y == yapprox /. sol

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks. Then, can I conclude that if  I use   ```     π Rationalize[
  1/π N[
    1.3174834093588992422968987309999004349851390189655838428664836598\
2808932066349`50.]]     
```  
 which gives $1.31748$ as a result, is not a rational multiple of $\pi$?

Comment: Yes, this value is not a simple rational multiple. By lowering the tolerance on `Rationalize` you can force a more complicated rational multiple of Pi.

Comment: Could you please give an example of how to lower tolerence?

Comment: Use the second argument to `Rationalize`, e.g., `1/Pi * 1.31748340935889924229689873099990043498513901896558384286648365982808932066349\`50. // Rationalize[#, 10^-5] &`

Answer (score 4):

Solve can solve the system exactly, given the evidence of `FindRoot`:

```
Solve[dif == {0, 0} && 4/10 < y < 45/100 && 14 < t < 145/10, {t, y}]

(*  {{t -> 225/16, y -> (2 π)/15}}  *)
```

Comment: Thanks. Then, can I conclude that if I use ``` π Rationalize[ 1/π N[ 1.3174834093588992422968987309999004349851390189655838428664836598\ 2808932066349`50.]] ``` which gives 1.31748 as a result, is not a rational multiple of π?

Comment: @charmin A floating-point number `x` comes with round-off error, which means it might be equal to (infinitely) many rational multiples of pi; however, they may all have large denominators. If `Rationalize[x]` does not return a rational number, it means it couldn't find a rational number $p/q$ with a small denominator, a $q$ such that $|p/q - x| < 10^-4/q^2$, according to the docs. The round-off error means you can never be absolutely certain, but your `Rationalize` approach means mistakes will probably be rare.

Answer (score 1):

`Rationalize[0.41887902047863909846168578443726705122628925325001/π]` gives `2/15`. Is that convincing enough?